# Fill a page with boxes using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

Say you've got a 100px by 100px container. You want to fill it with 5px by 5px "boxes". For the sake of simplicity you can ignore padding, border width, margin. Is there a way to declaratively do this using only CSS and HTML (without manually declaring the exact amount of boxes)?

**Edit**: My original intention was that the boxes are in fact elements. But I appreciate the creativity.

Comment: Nope, HTML is static and CSS works on HTML elements.

Answer (score 2):

Like @thanatosDM said if these boxes are html object then NO you can't. Else you can create some design effect using HTML & CSS.

This is the closest I can think of:

```css
p{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='5px' width='5px'><text x='0' y='5' fill='red' font-size='5'>box</text></svg>");
}
```

```html
<p>container</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If these "boxes" are individual HTML elements, then no, that is not possible with just HTML and CSS. You would need to use server-side code or JavaScript to generate them.

If these "boxes" are just visual elements, you can use a 5px by 5px background image, and then set `background-repeat: repeat;` in the CSS.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOtMo.png") 
              repeat
              top left/5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do these "boxes" need to be elements or just look like elements? You could use linear gradients to create the *appearance* of boxes, but they wouldn't *actually* be elements or containers.

```css
body { background: #eee; }
.outer, .inner { width: 100px; height: 100px;display: block; }
.outer { 
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px #aaa;
  background: #fff
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    
  background: #fff
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: #fff
    linear-gradient(to top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  }

.inner { 
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a00;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 3px #aaa;
  background: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(right, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    
  background: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(right, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 19%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 40%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 59%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 79%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 99%,
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"> YIPEE! </div></div>
```

You'd have to add several more gradient stops to get the 5px areas.. but it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

No, all objects in html need to be written out by the programmer, so you can't do so with those limitations